# How to setup my C# Winforms app using local SQL Server database with (or without) Windows authentication mode?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, authentication

I have developed a C# Winforms app with Visual Studio 2015 which uses a SQL Server 2014 local database.

I used ado.net to connect to database there is the connection string I used:

```
Data source=reza\mssqlserver2014;inital catalog=storesystem;integated security=true
```

And it works great on my pc.

What do I need and what should I do to set it up in another computer?

Note that I login to my SQL Server 2014 with Windows authentication mode.

I have tried backing up and restoring the `.mdf` file to target computer. But it didn't work.

Comment: You should change configuration of your database to support Sql server authentication [Connecting Through SQL Server Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode#connecting-through-sql-server-authentication).

Comment: use application configuration to control to use Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Your app is using Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server and I suspect your development machine's SQL instance already has been setup to recognise your account.

On the target machine, add the currently logged-in Windows user as a legitimate user for the database in question under **Logons**.

Though you could arguably move to SQL Server Authentication, a better security model is when the application does not use a password in the first place.

Comment: Micky - in this scenario, in the form load event, how can I check whether the windows user has certain permissions like db_datawriter and db_datareader so that if the user doesn't have these permissions then I want to do Application.Exit(). Please can you guide me.

Comment: @variable that sounds like an excellent _new question_.  Why not post it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861497/how-to-authenticate-using-the-database-role-of-windows-user-in-a-windows-forms-a