# How to authenticate using the database role of windows user in a windows forms app?

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am working on a windows forms application. My goal is to write code so that when the application is launched, if the windows user is member of atleast the *db_datareader* sql role then allow him to use the application otherwise exit.

My connection string is as follows:

`Data Source = svrname; Initial Catalog = dbname; Integrated Security = true`

On the main form load event I am making a sql query using the below code:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT IS_MEMBER('DB_DATAREADER');", con);
con.open();
var bool1 = Convert.ToBoolean(com.ExecuteScalar());

if(!bool1){
Application.Exit();
}

txtHeader = "Welcome!";
```

Is there any alternate way of doing this?

Comment: Surely the better idea would be that the connection would fail to the database, because they don't have a `LOGIN` or `USER` mapped to their AD credentials, if the user shouldn't have access, no?

Comment: So this can he handled using try catch block on the execute scalar? Otherwise I have a global error handler to catch such errors anyways.

Comment: I'm  just, personally, confused why you are checking if the user has the in build database role `db_datareader` and then exiting. Why does the user have access to the database (and I therefore assume just has the `public` role) in the first place? Surely if they shouldn't have access to the database, they shouldn't have a mapped `USER` on the database.

Comment: The users of the app will only ever have db_datareader role. Any user who doesn't have this role is to be considered invalid.

Comment: But the above doesn't check if they *only* have the `db_datareader` role; just if they have it (they could have other roles too). Also, a `sysadmin` will return `1` even though they may not explicitly have said role. I feel like this is turning into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Ok I get your point. What is the way to do this.

Comment: Can I say this is OK to check if the user has got atleast the db_datareader role? Irrespective of whether it is got db_datareader via the role itself or any higher role?

Comment: You can handle with a try/catch.  Users who are not part of the group will get an exception when trying to connect to the database.  Others will not get the exception.

Comment: @larnu - do custom roles (if I create a new db role with datareader checkmarked) behave the same way - that is does dbowner automatically have access to custom roles?